# c# bool rows count with empty columns every time true

Tags: c#

I have 2 columns `book1` and `book2`to in `Borrowes` table but some time users borrowed the book and some time no, so I need to delete user which not borrowed any book (`book1` or `book2`).  I got every time value in True. Let me know what can i do thanks.

I tried this...

```
 con.Open();

 bool readerHasRows = false;
 string brid = txtBr_id.Text;
 String syntax = "SELECT book1, book2 FROM Borrowes WHERE brId = @brid";

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(syntax, con))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brid", txtBr_id.Text);


     using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
        readerHasRows = (!reader[0].IsDBNull);
     }
 }
 con.Close();

 if (readerHasRows == true)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("This borrower has borrowed the book please collect the book first.");
 }
```

Comment: You need to change your SQL for comparison. Right now you're only fetching rows which will always be total number of rows in database by borrower id.

Comment: i am a student, i tried many things. to search from stack-overflow but i dosn't get any solution.. :( can you please make me the solution? i also tried this `readerHasRows = (reader != null && reader.HasRows);`

Comment: in case user not borrowed there will be now row in table?

Comment: putting `readerHasRows = reader.read()` should make your code work but you'd probably also need a better DB model. The one you have does not make much sense.

Comment: i need just if empty column `book1` or `book2` then i need value false if `book1` or `book2` not null so i need value false in `readerHasRows`.

Comment: @Vahid same problem.. `readerHasRows = reader.read()` get also `true` value in `readerHasRows`

Comment: If you set the book1 and book2 to null when the user has borrowed no books you should also change your query to something like this: `String syntax = "SELECT book1, book2 FROM Borrowes WHERE brId = @brid AND (book1 IS NOT NULL OR book2 IS NOT NULL)";`

Comment: Why there is a row in the table if borrower has not borrow any book?

Comment: @Vahid with this query working... 
`String syntax = "SELECT book1, book2 FROM Borrowes WHERE brId = @brid AND (book1 IS NOT NULL OR book2 IS NOT NULL)"`

Comment: glad to know. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set book1 and book2 to null for the users who'd borrowed no books:

```
 con.Open();

 bool readerHasRows = false;
 string brid = txtBr_id.Text;
 String syntax = "SELECT book1, book2 FROM Borrowes WHERE brId = @brid AND (book1 IS NOT NULL OR book2 IS NOT NULL)";

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(syntax, con))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brid", txtBr_id.Text);


     using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
        readerHasRows = reader.read();
     }
 }
 con.Close();

 if (readerHasRows == true)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("This borrower has borrowed the book please collect the book first.");
 }
```